# Edittext to int crashes

Tags: java, android, xml

So basically, I've just started android development and was building an app from a tutorial on youtube. I decided to go off a bit and make it the way i want it, and now I'm getting an error.

What I'm trying to do is allow a EditText to decide the increment amount of this counter application. Here is my code:

Java Activity:

```
        counter = 0;
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        addone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        takeOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take);
        tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        incrementer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

        final int increment = Integer.parseInt(incrementer.getText().toString());

        addone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter += increment;
                tvCounter.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });

        takeOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter -= increment;
                tvCounter.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter = 0;
                tvCounter.setText("" + counter);
            }
```

XML:

```
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add One" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/take"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Take One" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, and show us how the above code is contained (is it in a method, class scope, etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
02-17 09:35:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(3177): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
02-17 09:35:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(3177):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
02-17 09:35:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(3177):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
02-17 09:35:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(3177):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
02-17 09:35:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(3177):     at
```

That might be the error and spotted on this line

```
final int increment = Integer.parseInt(incrementer.getText().toString());
```

It is better to put a default value to your `EditText`

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="0" 
        android:inputType="number" >
```

Comment: Ok i've done this and I know this may sound stupid, but it isn't actually adding to the number. Do I have to add a button or something where it actually registers the increment value, rather then just typing it in?

Comment: You don't need to add button

Answer (score 0):

It probably crashes because the content of your EditText is not a number.
Assuming this is your onCreate method, you don't need to read the edittext at this point.
Parse the content of the edittext in the onClick methods of the buttons, before updating your counter.

Also, since you don't know what kind of text the user inputs, you should surround the parseInt call with a try and catch to prevent the app from crashing in case the EditText doesn't contain a number.

Add `android:text="1"` to your EditText in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You got empty EditText and trying to parseInt from "", you will got NumberFormatException from Integer.parseInt("") method.

Just use try/catch to catch and handle exception.

```
final int increment;
try {
    increment = Integer.parseInt();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Do what you want
}
```